# How to correctly plot function with space?

Tags: functions, graphing-functions

I want to include some plots of some functions which approaches certain values. See the screenshot below of **tanh**.

For clarity I have added some space left and right.

However I think **this is not correct, because this suggest that e.g. x=4.2 is outside the domain** which is not te case.

How is this typically solved? Is this just fine (I am too critical), or is this solved on an another way (add plot domain in legend)?

Thanks

[image]

Comment: What program are you using?

Comment: @Martin: PGF Plot, see my Minimal Working Example, added to my top post

Comment: Definitely a question for TeX Stack Exchange.

Comment: Not for the TEX Site, because I am asking a generic question (independent from tool/etc). I want to know how to show this mathematically correct.

Answer (score 1):

Few years late here, but I think the best solution would have been to show the vertical asymptotes in the standard way -- with dashed lines. One possible `pgfplots` solution is:

```
\documentclass[10pt, a4paper]{article}

\usepackage{pgfplots}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{axis}[xmin = -5, xmax = 5,
          ymin = -1.5, ymax = 1.5]

\addplot[mark = none] {tanh(x)};

\addplot[mark = none, dashed] {1};

\addplot[mark = none, dashed] {-1};

\end{axis}

\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Which gives:

[image]

Add axis labels/increase `samples` as desired.